# trying to customize the python nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I've trying to convert list to tuples to customized list to dictionaries. I'm able toto divide admin, pack owner, submitter, consumer and read only. Please check below code and output

```
from collections import defaultdict

role_details = ['po','sub', 'cons', 'admin','read']

lst = [('name1', 'email1', 'psid1', 'new1', 11, '1', 'po'),
       ('name2', 'email2', 'psid2', 'new2', 12, '2', 'sub'),
       ('name3', 'email3', 'psid3', 'new3', 13, '3', 'sub'),
       ('name4', 'email4', 'psid4', 'new4', 14, '4', 'po'),
       ('name5', 'email5', 'psid5', 'new5', 15, '5', 'cons')]

by_role = defaultdict(list)

for name, email, psid, new, id1, id2, role_name in lst:
    by_role[role_name].append({"name": name, "email": email, "psid": psid})

print({"add_sub": dict(by_role)})
```

output:

```
{'add_sub': 
  {'po': [{'name': 'name1', 'email': 'email1', 'psid': 'psid1'}, {'name': 'name4', 'email': 'email4', 'psid': 'psid4'}],
   'sub': [{'name': 'name2', 'email': 'email2', 'psid': 'psid2'}, {'name': 'name3', 'email': 'email3', 'psid': 'psid3'}],
   'cons': [{'name': 'name5', 'email': 'email5', 'psid': 'psid5'}]
  }
}
```

but if any of the role details record not exit in the lst i'm trying to pass an empty list. Please check the expected output

expected output:

```
{'add_sub':
  {'admin': [], 
  'po': [{'name': 'name1', 'email': 'email1', 'psid': 'psid1'}, {'name': 'name4', 'email': 'email4', 'psid': 'psid4'}],
  'read': [],
   'sub': [{'name': 'name2', 'email': 'email2', 'psid': 'psid2'}, {'name': 'name3', 'email': 'email3', 'psid': 'psid3'}],
   'cons': [{'name': 'name5', 'email': 'email5', 'psid': 'psid5'}]
  }
}
```

I'm new to python plz suggest me with logic. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also create the `dict` with all the keys you need beforehand. In this case you don't even need the `defaultdict`, unless you need its functionality later.

```
#from collections import defaultdict

role_details = ['pack owner','submitter', 'consumer', 'admin','read only']

lst = [('name1', 'email1', 'psid1', 'new1', 11, '1', 'pack owner'),
       ('name2', 'email2', 'psid2', 'new2', 12, '2', 'submitter'),
       ('name3', 'email3', 'psid3', 'new3', 13, '3', 'submitter'),
       ('name4', 'email4', 'psid4', 'new4', 14, '4', 'pack owner'),
       ('name5', 'email5', 'psid5', 'new5', 15, '5', 'consumer')]

#by_role = defaultdict(list)
by_role = {k: [] for k in role_details}

for name, email, psid, new, id1, id2, role_name in lst:
    by_role[role_name].append({"name": name, "email": email, "psid": psid})

print({"add_sub": by_role})
```

```
{'add_sub': 
   {'pack owner': [{'name': 'name1', 'email': 'email1', 'psid': 'psid1'}, {'name': 'name4', 'email': 'email4', 'psid': 'psid4'}], 
   'submitter': [{'name': 'name2', 'email': 'email2', 'psid': 'psid2'}, {'name': 'name3', 'email': 'email3', 'psid': 'psid3'}], 
   'consumer': [{'name': 'name5', 'email': 'email5', 'psid': 'psid5'}], 
   'admin': [], 
   'read only': []}
}
```

Also note that you don't need the `dict()` call in the print, since `by_role` is already a `dict`.

If you **do** need the `defaultdict`, you can do the same thing with this line:

```
from collections import defaultdict

# ...code...

by_role = defaultdict(list, {k: [] for k in role_details})
```

Answer (score 1):

`by_role` is a `defaultdict(list)`, so you'll get an empty list if you try to access the `by_role['admin']` or `by_role['read only']`.

In fact, all you need to do is try to access those keys once, and they get added to the `defaultdict`, so you can iterate over `role_details` and do that:

```
for name, email, psid, new, id1, id2, role_name in lst:
    by_role[role_name].append({"name": name, "email": email, "psid": psid})

for role_name in role_details:
   _ = by_role[role_name] # Try to access every key, and don't do anything with it.
```

Then, you should have your expected output:

```
{'add_sub': {
    'pack owner': [
         {'name': 'name1', 'email': 'email1', 'psid': 'psid1'},
         {'name': 'name4', 'email': 'email4', 'psid': 'psid4'}
     ],
    'submitter': [
         {'name': 'name2', 'email': 'email2', 'psid': 'psid2'},
         {'name': 'name3', 'email': 'email3', 'psid': 'psid3'}
     ],
    'consumer': [{'name': 'name5', 'email': 'email5', 'psid': 'psid5'}],
    'admin': [],
    'read only': []
   }
}
```